# Access a tree by level without traversing

Tags: algorithms, data-structures

I need a tree structure that works roughly like the following

- for each new child I need to match it (with some criteria) with a parent from the previous level only
- when the tree is completely initialized, for each leaf I need to find the first <s>parent</s> *ancestor* that has siblings, i.e. the node just after the branching point.

While the latter is pretty easy with a tipical tree structure, for the first I'd like to just access all nodes of a layer without traversing the whole tree (even with BFS). Does this have a name?

I'm thinking to just keep track of level number for each node and build a second structure to represent levels.

Comment: The wording is [slightly unusual](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)#Terminology_used_in_trees) in my eyes: for a `child`, there should be *exactly one `parent`*, which should be known/well-defined on insertion(`new`): are you talking about *potential* parents to select from? `First parent` might be *first ancestor*.

Comment: You're right, I meant `ancestor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To support the operations mentioned - especially [*level-order traversal*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first_search) (or *walk*) - in time bounded by the depth, you don't need an extra attribute for each node.

For a "semi-static" tree¹, you could use an array of *node*s to store it:
For every *level*, keep the index just beyond.
For every node, keep *parent*, for non-*leaf nodes*, *children* ("first" child), too:
*siblings* are successive nodes with same parent.

For a "dynamic" tree, modify the `[typical] tree structure` keeping children, siblings and optionally parent to support level-order traversal:
Change sibling to *next in same level* - not a sibling iff different parent.
You may need support for *first in level*, or "the list of nodes in the same level" to be circular to be able to access all of them starting from any-one thereof.

[1]: *semi-static tree*: only structural change is addition of nodes.
(The task sketched *may* have another restriction: no node with children will get another child once a different node gets one.)
(or even *static*: `[once] the tree is completely initialized`)

Answer (score 0):

If it’s a complete tree, you could use an array to store it. Accessing parents, siblings, and children would be quite simple and you wouldn’t have to traverse the tree.

Comment: It's not complete, any node could have any number of children. The only thing I know in advance is the number of layers. Another thing I can exploit is that once it's initialized it's fixed, and I only need to climb it backwards from leaves looking for branching points.